Does deleting an image from a model delete it from the media folder?
I'm making a social networking website project to practice Django
I am curious as to whether deleting an image from a model also deletes it from the media folder?
For example, I have a field in my User model where a user can upload their profile picture.
As standard, I save that profile picture in my media folder and a reference to that media folder is used by my model to load it.
But, if the user wishes to delete that picture, I use User.profilepic.delete()
to delete it
Does that mean that the picture also gets deleted from the media folder or I have to handle that separately?
I tried looking it up on the net but I couldn't find a direct answer.
All of the articles talk about deleting the image from the DATABASE.
But none from the folder.

in Django, when you delete a file field from a model instance using delete(), it doesn't automatically delete the file from the media folder. You need to handle the deletion of the file from the media folder separately...

The answer is not very clear to me, you first say you delete a file using .delete(), next you say it does not, so it seems you contradict yourself. Is it possible to make the answer more clear?

When you delete a file field from a model instance in Django using the delete() method, Django doesn't automatically remove the corresponding file from the media folder. You'll need to take care of deleting the file from the media folder yourself.

Thank you @Mahiboob. I tried it out and yes, you are right. I have to handle the media folder delete separately. Thank you

It's my pleasure @aaditya can you give me vote so that my answer to appear in top

Hello, @Mahiboob . I would love to upvote your answer but I can't due to "reputation" constraint.  I am extremely sorry. But I am very very thankful for your answer.


I am curious as to whether deleting an image from a model also deletes it from the media folder?

Yes, if you use some_user.profilepic.delete(), it will, since some_user.profilepic is a FieldFile [Django-doc] (not to be confused with a FileField [Django-doc]), and we call .delete(…) [Django-doc] on this:

FieldFile.delete(save=True)
Deletes the file associated with this instance and clears all attributes on the field. Note: This method will close the file if it happens to be open when delete() is called.

Whether the file can be removed however depends on the storage, since there can be a storage backend that does not allow removing files.
Beware that if you remove the some_user itself, it will not clean up media files it refers to, so:
some_user.delete()  # will not remove the profilepic, but database record
some_user.profilepic.delete()  # remove the file, not the record
Removing files that way however is seldomly a good idea: other models might refer to the same file, and thus then link to a file that no longer exists.
You can work with a management command provided by django-unused-media [pypi.org] for example that will look for media files for which no model exists with a FileField that links to that file.

But I tried working with profile_pic.delete() It only removed the record in the database. My media folder still contained the file. So, now I have decided to implement a solution using the os module. I retrieve the path of the profile picture from its object. And then delete it using os.remove()

@aadityajindal: but what is profile_pic? A model object, or the field of that model object?

Hello, @willeM_Van_Onsem profile_pic is another object in itself. I decided to make it another object as I require it as another object in other places in the project. However, the issue is now resolved. Thank you for your time and help. . However, you are right. This is also a possible solution. I can delete the picture held in profile_pic first using your method and then delete the object itself. So yes, this is also a good solution.

@aadityajindal: well if it is a model object, then no, it will not remove the file. You can use profile_pic.image_field.delete() with image_field the name of the field that stores the image. I think the confusion thus stems from the fact that a model_object.delete() is something different than model_object.image_field.delete().
